# server side script for AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In writing my first program that uses jQuery's .ajax() function to ask a server side PHP script for data and then process it, I am struggling to come up with an appropriate file name for the PHP script.  Is there a naming convention or a standard file name for a script whose purpose is to receive requests and send back data to AJAX calls?  What file names are you using for your server side scripts that handle AJAX calls?

Comment: No. But you can write more details about your code to get help.

Comment: It's personal preference, or your company's standard.  There is no best practice for naming PHP files.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332741/are-questions-about-convention-or-style-advice-on-topic-for-stack-overflow?cb=1

Comment: Agree with @devlin. Stick with your convention naming. You can store your file in a separate _ajax_ folder for more clarity. Up to you to choose a smart name for the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should consider adopting a [RESTful naming convention](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) if it makes sense to model your domain in that way. You name your endpoint after the resource it represents. Sometimes REST is overkill and doesn't add value (especially if the model doesn't fit, and/or nobody else will ever use your API).

Nine times out of ten, if you're having trouble naming something, it's because you're trying to make it do too many things at once. If an API endpoint (or a function, or a class, etc etc etc) is hard to name, ask yourself if you could make it more granular/break out its various concerns.

Comment: This is very helpful.  The PHP script currently contains 3 different functions and there is an IF block that fires the appropriate function according to a $caller variable from the JS.  Perhaps these functions should be split into separate PHP scripts and then the script naming would be more obvious.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That sounds like a good way forward.

Comment: this really has nothing to do with file naming conventions for PHP files called by AJAX.